# How to choose Bluetooth controller in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

My Mac Pro's [internal bluetooth is broken](http://blog.armhold.com/2009/11/16/apple-fails-at-customer-service/). For the past 2 years, I've been getting by just fine with a USB Bluetooth adapter. I had to temporarily remove that adapter recently, and after putting it back I find that Lion has reverted to using the internal (broken!) adapter again.

Usually this is fixed simply by going into some utility program (Utilities -> Bluetooth Prefs?), which I no longer find in OS X.

Instead, I have only the System Preferences Bluetooth controls, and they do not allow me to specify the controller.  How can I choose the Bluetooth controller in OS X Lion?